# ERROR ObjectUnsubscribedErrorImpl {message: 'object unsubscribed', name: 'ObjectUnsubscribedError

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error when I navigate back to a screen where I call certain code in my directive. On the first time I get to the screen, everything works as expected but when I return then I see this error.

`ERROR  ObjectUnsubscribedErrorImpl {message: 'object unsubscribed', name: 'ObjectUnsubscribedError'} message: "object unsubscribed" name: "ObjectUnsubscribedError"`

I have checked that I unsubscribe in my `unsubscribeFromKeyboardEvents` method

Here is my code

```
...
@Directive({
  selector: '[appOskInput]',
})
export class OskInputDirective implements OnInit {
  ...

  constructor(
    @Optional() private control: NgControl,
    private el: ElementRef,
    private keyboard: KeyboardService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let thisStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this.el.nativeElement);
    this.measure = document.createElement('span');
    this.measure.style.position = 'absolute';
    this.measure.style.right = '100%';
    this.measure.style.font = thisStyle.font;
    document.body.appendChild(this.measure);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.el.nativeElement instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      this.inputEl = this.el.nativeElement;
      return;
    }
    this.inputEl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
  }

  @HostListener('focus')
  private onFocus() {
    this.isBlurTrue = false;
    this.blurChanged.emit(this.isBlurTrue);
    this.keyboard.fireKeyboardRequested(true);
    this.subscribeToKeyboardEvents();
  }

  @HostListener("onBlur")
  private onBlur() {
    this.isBlurTrue = true;
    this.blurChanged.emit(this.isBlurTrue);
    this.keyboard.fireKeyboardRequested(false);
    this.unsubscribeFromKeyboardEvents();
  }

  private subscribeToKeyboardEvents() {
    this.keySubscription = this.keyboard.keyPressed.subscribe((key) =>
      this.onKey(key)
    );
    this.backspaceSubscription = this.keyboard.backspacePressed.subscribe((_) =>
      this.onBackspace()
    );
    this.enterSubscription = this.keyboard.enterPressed.subscribe((_) =>
      this.onEnter()
    );
  }

  private unsubscribeFromKeyboardEvents() {
    this.keySubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.backspaceSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.enterSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  private onKey(key: string) {
    let element = this.inputEl,
      start = element.selectionStart,
      end = element.selectionEnd;
    this.measure.textContent = element.value.substr(0, start) + key;
    element.value = element.value.substr(0, start) + key + element.value.substr(end);
    if (this.control) this.control.control.setValue(element.value);
    element.focus();
    element.selectionStart = element.selectionEnd = start + 1;
    this.inputChanged.emit(element.value);
    this.updateScrollPosition();
  }

  private onBackspace() {
    let element = this.inputEl,
      start = element.selectionStart,
      end = element.selectionEnd;

    if (start == 0) {
      return;
    }

    if (start == end) {
      start--;
    }

    this.measure.textContent = element.value.substr(0, start);
    element.value = element.value.substr(0, start) + element.value.substr(end);
    if (this.control) this.control.control.setValue(element.value);
    element.focus();
    element.selectionStart = element.selectionEnd = start;
    this.inputChanged.emit(element.value);
    this.updateScrollPosition();
  }

  private updateScrollPosition() {
    let element = this.el.nativeElement;
    element.scrollLeft = this.measure.offsetWidth - (element.clientWidth - 10);
  }

  private onEnter() {
    const ev = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
      code: 'Enter',
      key: 'Enter'
    });
    this.el.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(ev);
  }
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Whoever requested for the question to be closed, can you please explain why?

Comment: You need to let go of manual DOM subscription... this is a nightmare to manage in angular, as you can see. I advise a refactor of this code with [reactive forms](https://angular.io/api/forms/ReactiveFormsModule), this way you can subscribe to value changes, instead of blur and focus

Comment: I am also voting to close this question, as you need more focus on a specific problem, and asking "what is wrong with my code" is usually not well received.